# 'str' object has no attribute 'save' Django

Tags: python, django

```
class AgentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # agents = dashboard_userlink.objects.filter(username__in=Subquery(task_router_calldetail.objects.values('agent').distinct())).values_list('username').annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '),'last_name')).order_by('first_name')
        agents = dashboard_userlink.objects.values('username').distinct().values_list('username').annotate(full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '),'last_name')).order_by('first_name')
        for i in agents:
            agent_name = i[0]
            agent_value = i[1]
            if agent_value == ' ':
                agent_value = agent_name
                agent_value.save()
        agent_list = [('','Select')] + list(agents)
        super(AgentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['agent'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=agent_list )
```

Comment: `save` operates on model instances, not values.  notice the `.values(...` in your query, you won't return the actual model instances, just values from them

Answer (score 0):

Check the code part below

```
        if agent_value == ' ':
            agent_value = agent_name
            agent_value.save()
```

the `agents` variable you are using has no model instance (I think you are expecting a model instance) instead is just a string value hence`agent_value.save()` throwing the error

Answer (score -1):

Here you are using values(), it returns dictionaries not an instance of model. You can use save() to save instance. Save is used to save an object to database.

Thanks